# Implementing reCaptcha with jQuery.validity

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, recaptcha

I'm validating a form with jQuery.validity, but I would like to add reCaptcha functionality.

As I'm using jQuery.validity, I don't know what should I put in "Your code here to handle a successful verification".

Here is the information about:

1. jQuery.validity.
2. reCaptcha.
3. My form.

http://pastebin.com/hZQzc43R

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to submit the form via AJAX to check against the validity of the captcha.. Fortunately your plugin offers that functionality...

[read here about Validity and AJAX](http://validity.thatscaptaintoyou.com/Demos/index.htm#UsingValidityWithAjax)

You will then need to understand how the server validates the captcha data.. [read here](http://code.google.com/apis/recaptcha/docs/php.html)

When the form is submitted, you will first check all form data for validity, displaying your errors where you find them. Then you will post the captcha data to the server and check to see if the returned value is true or false (see link provided for captcha information). If the value is false you can flag that container (the captcha container) as invalid and display an appropriate message.